# Accessing a given dimension of an array

Tags: r

suppose X is a D dimensional array.

I want to write a function with two arguments:

```
foo<-function(X,d){
   ....
}
```

where foo has to run on the d^th dimension of X. 
For example, extract the elements of the d^th dimension 
of X.

How can this be done (I'd rather use arrays and not lists)

Comment: for example, if `X` is a m-by-n matrix (2D array), what should `foo(X, 2)` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ended up solving it: the objective was to find a standard way of seamlessly replacing an `apply()` by a `lapply()` (because the latter can easily be be parrallelized). 
Here's an example for a trivial `apply()`

```
#data
n<-10
p<-5
k<-15
x<-array(rnorm(n*p*k),dim=c(n,p,k))


fx01<-function(ll,x,d0,dm,fun1){
    dm[[d0]]<-ll
    gotfun<-get(fun1)
    gotfun(x[dm[[1]],dm[[2]],dm[[3]]])
}

#housekeeping:
d0<-3
lx<-length(dim(x))
dm<-vector("list",lx)
for(i in 1:lx) dm[[i]]<-1:dim(x)[i]

#the actual computations:
res<-lapply(1:dim(x)[d0],fx01,x=x,d0=d0,dm=dm,fun1="mean")
c(res,recursive=TRUE)
#compare with the real thing:
apply(x,d0,mean)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your array has D dimensions, than you cannot refer to a single dimension by specifying a scalar. Instead, you need to supply a vector of dimensions. For instance, if your array is:

```
set.seet(123)
X <- array(data=rnorm(12),dim=c(2,2,3))
```

then e.g. `X[2]` will give you a single element of the array. If you try `X[2,1]`, you will get the error about incorrect number of dimensions. So the only option to acquire a whole dimension is to provide a vector of length D, where one of the elements will be empty e.g. `X[1,1,]`. This will give you the respective dimension of the array, in this particular example consisting of 3 element, which corresponds to the definition.

Naturally, other (specified) dimensions can vary within the boundaries defined, e.g. `X[1,2,]`.

Answer (score 0):

see `?apply`, here's a simple example:

```
x = array(c(1:8), dim = c(2,2,2))
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    5    7
#[2,]    6    8

apply(x, 3, sum)
#[1] 10 26
```